# How to check who interacted with discord.py 2.0 component

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord.py 2.0 button component, I need to make sure the person who clicks the button is the one who initiated the prompt. But I don't know how to get the person who clicks the button so I can compare it too `ctx.author`. Here is what I have so far.

```
@bot.command()
async def prompt(ctx):
    positive = Button(label="Yes", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    negative = Button(label="No", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)

    async def positive_callback(interaction):
        if ctx.button == ctx.author:  # ctx.button is not a real argument, that is what needs to be the user who clicks the button.
            await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"{ctx.author.mention} Here is some cake ❤", view=None)

    positive.callback = positive_callback

    view = View()
    view.add_item(positive)
    view.add_item(negative)
    await ctx.send(content=f"{ctx.author.mention} Would you like to have some cake?", view=view)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ctx.author`, you should use `interaction.user` like so:

```
async def positive_callback(interaction):
  if interaction.user == ctx.author:
    await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"{ctx.author.mention} Here is some cake ❤", view=None)
```